# Can't change "on click" property in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm  just starting to learn how to develop android apps, and I'm following a for dummies book.

I dragged a button on to the screen and I was able to change the text by clicking on it and changing the value of "text" in the properties tab on the right side of the screen.

Now I want to change what it does, but the "on click" value in the properties tab on the right side of the screen is grayed out so I can't type in the name of the method that I want the button to call. In fact, all of the values are grayed out except for width, height, text, and ID, but in the book, it shows the values being editable.

I am using the version of eclipse that came with the android adt bundle, on windows 8.1 running classicshell

Comment: Try using xml if you cannot edit from the graphic view. Plus you can work faster. I never used the graphic view except for first 10 pimuties on my first app. Great decision as I can make layouts really fast now.

Answer (score 0):

its better and easy to edit in xml like :

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrapcontent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/pub"
        android:onClick="callurmethodhere"/>
```